# I can not change branches once the postsharp library is included

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2013, postsharp

When I try to change my postsharp branch (I'm porbando this extension with the free license in my project) and it gives me this error in with git, I can say that it can be

Could not rmdir 'C: /Users/johanAdmin/Repos/ProcessEDT/packages/PostSharp.4.3.33/lib/net35-client/PostSharp.xml': Access is denied.

Comment: Perhaps VS is locking the file. Try to close it before switching. Otherwise, use 'process Explorer' to find what is locking the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this has nothing to do with Postsharp but rather with xml files in Nuget packages. According to this https://github.com/microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/57 it was a problem with C# and F# projects using Nuget packages with XML files in VS2013 and back. So you should probably just upgrade to VS2017.

Comment: If it works, change to vs2015 and there was no problem, thanks for your answer, I did not update because there are things that still do not work for me in that version, for example component of devexpress :)